# I Wouldn't Ask Jeeves

Tags: riddle, knowledge

You've probably seen my buddies and I several times today. You may even have talked to us! We're pretty much inseparable, and we've played a lot of games over the years - usually fancy dress, but occasionally others, and always for a special occasion.

Our leader is the oldest, and rather melancholy. He's mostly here to keep an eye on his little brother. He sometimes goes off on his own, though, and when he does he has a much wider range of emotion. Or so I've been told.

Then come the twins - the hothead and the fraidy-cat. Sometimes, they bring their cousins along. I've never been able to get a good number on them, but there are a lot - thousands, or even millions, at first glance.

Then comes our leader's little brother, though you wouldn't know it at first glance. He cries a lot, but he means well. He's also a bit odd sometimes, and likes hanging off things, always dangling his legs over the ledge.

Then there's me, the tall one. I'm almost as tall as our leader, despite being closer in age to his little brother. Makes you wonder why he's in charge. Not that I'm jealous.

And after me comes the quiet one. He's a bit grumpy, but I like him. I know I wouldn't be able to speak up as well I do without him by my side.

**Who are we? And who am I?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You all are:

> Google and you are the letter 'l'.

*we've played a lot of games over the years*

> The Google logo is often decorated to refer to great persons or events. The leader is 'G', as it is the only capital letter.

*the twins - the hothead and the fraidy-cat*

> twins as there are two 'o's (and sometimes it's written with even more) and a hint towards their colours, red and yellow.

*Then comes our leader's little brother...always dangling his legs over the ledge.*

> The little brother is also a 'g' and goes farther down than the others.

*Then there's me, the tall one...And after me comes the quiet one.*

> So you are 'l', taller than the others except 'G'. And 'e' is 'the quiet one', as it is silent.

As for your title...

> ask.com was formerly known as Ask Jeeves.

This is my very first answer here and needless to say English isn't my first language, so sorry if I forgot something or formatting doesn't look good.

Comment: An excellent first answer - very nice Gahja. Welcome to Puzzling! :) (EDIT: I've improved the formatting for you - you'll pick up tips on how to do it in time, don't worry :) Very nice spot on finding the answer though!)

Comment: Thank you Stiv :) Yes that looks better (and I managed to find my mistake regarding the spoiler tags).

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Good work. You even spotted the emotion correspondence.